# Mobius Transformation 3 conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Define what is meant by a Mobius transformation. Determine the unique ¨
Mobius transformation which sends

- $z = −1$ to $w = i$,
- $z =\infty$ to $w = 1$,
- $z = i$ to $w = 1 + i$.

Verify that, for this Mobius transformation, the real axis in ¨
the $z$-plane is mapped onto the circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin in the
$w$-plane.

When I was working this out I got the Mobius transformation to be $$z\mapsto {(2-i)z+1\over 1-iz}$$

This worked for mapping $-1$ and infinity to the circle of radius $1$ however did not work for $1$ as it did not map to the circle radius $1$.

Comment: Doesn't this map $\infty$ to $\frac{2-i}{-i}\neq1 ?$

Comment: May I ask how did you get 2-i/-i

Comment: Divide numerator and denominator by $z$ and let $z\to\infty$